# Custom filename extension (eg: www.mysite.com/test.custom/)

Tags: web-hosting

I pay for a webhost service running a LAMP combo and I was wondering if I could have a custom extension for my documents such as:

```
www.mysite.com/custom.extension
```

instead of:

```
www.mysite.com/custom.php
```

It works on my local XAMPP computer (without modifying anything) and I can name my files whatever I want, but I can't on my paid webhost; it just shows me the HTML as plain text.

Comment: To clarify:  Do you want your `custom.extension` file in the example to be interpreted by PHP as it would `custom.php`, and ultimately be delivered to the user as HTML?

Comment: it should be interpreted as PHP and shown as an HTML file

Comment: This is really something you should be discussing with your hosting provider...

Comment: @voretaq7♦ no. i think some of you may know how to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup Apache for that. Add a line like the following to your `httpd.conf`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .extension
```

and it should work.

Comment: Or possibly in your .htaccess if you do not have write permission to httpd.conf

Comment: @DavidHoude Most providers (and most sane server administrators) don't allow directives like `AddType` in `.htaccess` files...